# Concate and produce null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I try to make an exception for my function where is address is `null`, it did not have to print out the null value.

Here is my function:

```
if (UserAddress::where('address_2', '=', 'null')) {
                $a = UserAddress::select("*", DB::raw("CONCAT(user_addresses.address_1,' ',user_addresses.address_2,' ',user_addresses.city,' ' ,user_addresses.postcode,' ',user_addresses.state)  as full_address"))->pluck('full_address');
            }else{
                $a = UserAddress::select("*", DB::raw("CONCAT(user_addresses.address_1,' ',user_addresses.address_2,' ',user_addresses.city,' ' ,user_addresses.postcode,' ',user_addresses.state)  as full_address"))->pluck('full_address');
            }
```

When I die dump `$a`, the first produce `null` query.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as `=`, `<`, or `<>` to test for `NULL`.

Instead of `where('address_2', '=', 'null')`, try using the `whereNull()` function like so:

```
if (UserAddress::whereNull('address_2')) {
                $a = UserAddress::select("*", DB::raw("CONCAT(user_addresses.address_1,' ',user_addresses.address_2,' ',user_addresses.city,' ' ,user_addresses.postcode,' ',user_addresses.state)  as full_address"))->pluck('full_address');
            }else{
                $a = UserAddress::select("*", DB::raw("CONCAT(user_addresses.address_1,' ',user_addresses.address_2,' ',user_addresses.city,' ' ,user_addresses.postcode,' ',user_addresses.state)  as full_address"))->pluck('full_address');
            }
```

It can help to enable the query log to see what exactly you are querying on the database, then you can run it directly via phpmyadmin (or whatever you are using). Place `DB::enableQueryLog();` before you query, and `//dd(DB::getQueryLog())` after the query is executed for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it. Use empty string with CONCAT_WS

```
DB::raw("CONCAT_WS('',user_addresses.address_1,...
```